# Page gets reloaded for infinite time when a POST request is made through AJAX to FLASK API

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'm sending base64 image data to Flask API endpoint using AJAX every second for a total of 10 seconds. What am I facing is that when a single request is made my whole page gets reloaded for an infinite time until I close the page manually or stop the python server. How can I stop the webpage to get reloaded?

P.S.:- I'm opening a media channel for video and capturing frames from that video stream into a canvas and sending that canvas image to the FLASK end. This frame is being captured and an AJAX request is made for the same each second.

[HTML File - index.htm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUBPk.jpg)

[Python File - script.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUOzK.png)

Comment: Check on different browser or Force refresh the page`Hold Ctrl and click the Reload button` and try?

Comment: @SreekantShenoy I want to stop the webpage from getting reloaded not to reload it.

Comment: Yea, The code looks fine, I think the page might have caching issue. Just force reload the page and try again.